# Switch position of short description and variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

What hook should I add/remove to switch the position of the short description and the variations.

So variations on top. Short description right below that.

ONLY ON MOBILE.[image: Image shows the setup now]

" id="product-" >
    
        
            ">
                
                    
                
            
            ">

```
                <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
                ?>

            </div><!-- .summary -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
</div>
```

-->

Comment: Does the variations live in a different folder?

Comment: How is this off topic? @toscho asked a valid question. Right now I don't know what hook to add/remove to switch the position of the variations and the short description

Comment: It is plugin specific. See [on-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please ask the plugin support.

Comment: How is this plugin specific?!??! a similar question is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831995/how-to-move-product-variation-descriptons-in-woocommerce It got a straight answer.

Comment: Even without the variations plugin I am using there would still be an option dropdown which I would like to do the same exact thing with. Move it to the top.